# positioning div containers and resizing browser issues

Tags: css, html

I am having the following aspx page and corresponding css file. When I try to resize the the browser vertically, scroll bar shows after a limit becoz of **overflow:scroll**, but not while resizing horizontally???  And also I have used **position:fixed** for positioning all divs,Is that ok??? Will some problem arise over other browsers???

**Aspx file:**

```
 <div id="container_div">
    <div id="header">
        Software Technology Limited
    </div>

    <div id="left_column">
        My name is krishnaraj...!!!
    </div>

    <div id="main_column">
        Instruction:<br /><br />
        Total number of questions : 20.<br />
        Time alloted : 30 minutes.<br />
        Each question carry 1 mark, no negative marks.<br />
        <asp:Button ID="butStartTest" runat="server" Text="Start Test..."/>
   </div>

   <div id="footer">
        &copy;2010 Software Technology Limited
   </div>
</div>
```

**Css file:**

```
#header
{
    border:brown 2px solid;    
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:30px;
}

#left_column
{
    border:blue 2px solid;    
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:34px;    
    bottom:24px;    
    width:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

#main_column
{
    border:green 2px solid;    
    position:fixed;
    left:204px;
    top:34px;
    right:0px;   
    bottom:24px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

#footer
{
    border:brown 2px solid;    
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set, `position:relative` it will be helpful in what you are trying to achieve. If you want horizontal scroll, you can try this:

`overflow-y: scroll;`

I am not very sure of what you are trying to achieve, but if you are looking out to build a responsive website, you are on a wrong path wince you are talking about resizing the browser windows.

Answer (score 0):

**Use overflow:auto instead of scroll this may solve your problems**

&

*if you want your layout to be fixed positioned their is no problem in that case to use position absolute but i would suggest to use relative or static(by default) position for more flexibility in your design.*